# What can cause custom UITableViewCell to blink on reload tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, exception, reloaddata

I have a problem with custom UITableViewCell. When i reload table view with methods: reload data(), beginUpdate()/endUpdate(), reloadRowsAtIndexPath() often my uitableviewcells blink, but not always. What can cause such problem?
Additional information:Cell has background alpha 0;all cells have different heights;i'm sure i reload data in main thread.
Thanks for help.